# Motorola DS9208 control character replacement

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

So I'm trying to scan US drivers licenses into a javascript browser app (In GWT).
The licenses contain LineFeed characters, and the scanner sends this to the host by sending ctrl+J.

This however doesn't work for most browsers because ctrl+J is a browser shortcut and thus my javascript never receives the event.

Apparently you can use ADF (Advanced data formatting) to do character replacement, however you can't do that with control characters because in their configuration tool the UI element you use to specify the string to be replaced is a text field, and you can't put control characters into a text field.

I've also tried to use the embedded driver license scanning programming, however my scanner always gives the wrong beeps when I attempt to program it and so I'm stuck there too.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Can I tell the browser to turn off shortcuts? Can I get the scanner to do control character replacement?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I am working on a similar project right now, and so far what I have found is that you can use jQuery to at least block the sending of the CTRL+J, CTRL+6, and CTRL+M control characters.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
if((event.ctrlKey) && (event.which == 74) ){
    event.preventDefault();
} else if((event.ctrlKey) && (event.which == 54)){
    event.preventDefault();
} else if((event.ctrlKey) && (event.which == 77)){
    event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

I have this working at http://jsfiddle.net/n8felton/CTTmu. For now the box on the left accepts the input, and the box on the right shows the control characters that are being sent.

If you get any further on this, I'd love to know. I'm currently attempting to figure out how to change a CTRL + J into a simple new line character.

Comment: Works a charm for me. Will keep looking and, if I find a more complete solution, try to remember to report back. Meantime, thanks for the fiddle!